# How to use constructor value of ReactiveDict

Tags: meteor

I have seen the constructor value of ReactiveDict a few times, but what is the usage of "myDict"?

```
var dict = new ReactiveDict('myDict');
```

> If you provide a name to its constructor, its contents will be saved
>   across Hot Code Push client code updates.

Whose contents will be saved here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> Whose contents will be saved here?

The reactive dict's contents. In you case, `dict`'s contents.

---

If you've observed, whenever you make changes to your code and save, meteor automatically restarts it's client or server depending on what was changed. 
Since `Sessions` are global in scope (amongst other things), their contents don't get wiped out with each "hot code push". Where as, for a reactive var/dict, since it's tied to the template, tends to get wiped out whenever a code push happens. In order to have the contents being persisted across hot code pushes, there is an option to pass a name to the constructor - which in turn tells meteor in the back-end to migrate EJSON-serializable data. (I've just skimmed through the code and believe this is what it does) :

```
var dict = new ReactiveDict('myDict');
```

If you check the [github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js) for reactive dict :

```
  // Get a JSON value that can be passed to the constructor to
  // create a new ReactiveDict with the same contents as this one
  _getMigrationData: function () {
    // XXX sanitize and make sure it's JSONible?
    return this.keys;
  }
});
```

Further scouting for what MigrationData stuff is, leads you to [this](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/migration.js). Some more information on migration is found [here](https://github.com/convexset/meteor-migration) :

> Migration is a Meteor package that supports migration of
>   EJSON-serializable data (on reloads triggered by hot code push) via a
>   simplified interface to Reload._onMigrate. The package supports
>   "template-level setups" that are torn down after template instances
>   are destroyed.

You may read more about it in this detailed [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Meteor/comments/2sos36/hot_code_push_how_does_it_work/) post.

Comment: So basically "new ReactiveDict('myDict');" will have the contents being persisted across hot code pushes while "new ReactiveDict()" will not. Correct?

Comment: @derek - While it's not explicitely stated anywhere about that being the case, it should be implied that ```new ReactiveDict()``` won't persist accross hotcode pushes.

Answer (score -1):

`ReactiveDict` is a [reactive data source](http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/48367809759/meteors-reactive-data-sources) in Meteor. Instance of `ReactiveDict` is very similar to `Session`, the only different thing is that Session is predefined and belongs to global scope.

You could use `ReactiveDict` as follow:

```
const dict = new ReactiveDict('mydict');

dict.set('hello', 'world');

dict.set({
  foo: 'bar',
});

dict.get('hello'); // => hello
dict.get('foo'); // => bar
```

Comment: Good copy. But no help on my question.

Comment: contents here means the values stored by the `ReactiveDict` instance, in my answer above they are `foo` and `hello`